# mvn fails on automounted directories

Tags: java, maven, nfs, automount

On a non-automounted filesystem, "mvn clean" works (so does "mvn package").  On a filesystem that's automounted, "mvn clean" fails in the following way:

```
 $ mvn clean
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Building glutmax-sentiment-analysis 1.0
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [WARNING] Failed to read tracking file /nethome/guest/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom.lastUpdated
 java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:90)
    [...]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
 Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
 [WARNING] Failed to write tracking file /nethome/guest/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom.lastUpdated
 java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:90)
    [...]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 04:13 min
 [INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-12T11:34:55-07:00
 [INFO] Final Memory: 23M/1445M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Input/output error -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException


 $ mvn -version
 Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T12:39:06-07:00)
 Maven home: /usr/local/maven
 Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
 Java home: /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/jre
 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
 OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Clearly, I'm missing some kind of configuration information, but searching for answers all I have found was that I need to delete ~/.m2/*, chmod 777 ~/.m2, and made sure my JAVA_HOME is correct.  None of the recommendations worked.  What am I missing?

Interestingly, **Gradle** doesn't appear to work on automounted filesystems either.

Comment: The user is able to create directories, files, change permissions, etc.  The "mount" output shows the user has "rw" permission: 10.10.10.10:/ms/ms.share/services/ps/guest on /nethome/guest type nfs (**rw**,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.20.30.70,mountvers=3,mountport=2049,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=10.20.30.70)

Comment: "The user is able to create directories" - which user? Are you sure it's the same user running the Maven job?

Comment: I believe so.  I can login and do a mkdir ~/.m2, but when I remove ~/.m2 and do a "mvn package", maven reports "Could not create local repository at /nethome/<user>/.m2/repository".  I've added "hard,nolock,noac" to the mount options, but still no joy.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a NFS issue. The JDK delegates to native function call for Linux, and the underlying syscall is failing. Try point Maven local repository directory to the local file system. To be specific, in file `apache-maven-${version}/conf/settings.xml`, uncomment and update line:

```
<localRepository>some_local_directory</localRepository>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to fix the write problem.

By adding **"hard,nolock,noac"** to the automount description, the user is now able to run **"mvn"**.  Unfortunately, a 1 minute build on a local filesystem takes approximately 15 minutes on an automounted filesystem.  But that's another question/problem for stackoverflow.